# How an element of std::map can delete itself from the map?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, std, stdmap

I have two classes in different source file, class `A` in `a.hpp` and `a.cpp`, class `B` in `b.hpp` and `b.cpp`, `A` is a `Singleton` class, it create `B` object, and store it in a map, when `B` object iscreated, it creates a thread, and I want `B`s object to remove itself from that map, which is `A`'s member when the thread exits, but my program throw a exception.

```
// main.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include "a.hpp"

int main() {
    A::get_instance().add(1);
    int pause = 0; std::cin >> pause;
    return 0;
}
```

```
// a.hpp

#ifndef __A_HPP__
#define __A_HPP__

#include <unordered_map>
#include <memory>
#include "b.hpp"

class A {
public:
    void add(int i);
    void remove(int i);
    static A& get_instance();
private:
    std::unordered_map<int, std::shared_ptr<B>> map_b_;
};


#endif
```

```
// a.cpp

#include "a.hpp"

void A::add(int i) {
    std::cout << "add: " << i << std::endl;
    map_b_[i] = std::move(std::make_shared<B>(i));
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(3s);
}
void A::remove(int i) {
    std::cout << "remove: " << i << std::endl;
    if (map_b_.count(i)) {
        map_b_.erase(i);
    }
}
A& A::get_instance() {
    static A instance;
    return instance;
}
```

```
// b.hpp

#ifndef __B_HPP__
#define __B_HPP__

#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

class B {
public:
    B(int id);
    ~B();
    void stop();
    void run();
private:
    std::atomic<bool> run_flag_;
    std::thread thr_;
    int id_;
};


#endif
```

```
b.cpp

#include "b.hpp"
#include "a.hpp"

B::B(int id) {
    id_ = id;
    run_flag_ = true;
    std::thread t(&B::run, this);
    thr_ = std::move(t);
}
B::~B() {
        std::cout << "~B(): " << id_ << std::endl;
    stop();
}
void B::stop() {
    run_flag_ = false;
    if (thr_.joinable()) {
        thr_.join();
    }
}
void B::run() {
    int count = 0;
    while (count < 3 && run_flag_) {
        std::cout << "processing id: " << id_ << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
        count ++;
    }
    A::get_instance().remove(id_);
}
```

```
# CMakeLists.txt
# CMake 最低版本号要求
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)

# 项目信息
project (demo)
SET(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Debug")
# 指定生成目标
add_executable(
    ${PROJECT_NAME} 
    main.cpp
    a.cpp
    b.cpp
)
find_package(Threads REQUIRED) 
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Threads::Threads)
```

i have run the code in my linux docker, but it throw an error, like this, i want know how can i do it to remove one itself from container.

```
root@53d8817a43a8:~/test-cpp/build# ./demo
add: 1
processing id: 1
processing id: 1
processing id: 1
remove: 1
~B(): 1
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Resource deadlock avoided
Aborted
```

Comment: Side note:  globals no mutexes and threads... you're going to run into race conditions at some point. Make an instance of A in main and make sure it outlives ALL the threads, or make a shared_ptr to A and pass a copy of that to each thread you start.

Comment: I would use the following scheme: Have A keep `weak_ptr`s, pass a `shared_ptr` to the (detached) thread, that keeps the B object alive until the thread ends. This will expire the `weak_ptr`. Then in `A::add`, garbage-collect expired `weak_ptr`s. Then you do not need `A::remove` and that  avoids the race condition in the `remove` call.

Comment: Someone just gave me an answer, but I don't know why the author deleted it, he tell me this, and is ok.
    this->thr_.detach();
    A::get_instance().remove(id_);

Comment: @shichao i removed it because a condition may happen when both `join` and `detach` will be called when an app tries to exit, and that is an unsolvable race condition, you need other means of synchronization that basically checks whether either `join` or `detach` has been called then **not** do the other, which will require an extra atomic.

Comment: @j6t i need export A to others, and i will keep many b object, and i have some more functions in A, other functions need find one b by id, update or read some member in b,  so i need save them , and update the map in runing.

Comment: @PepijnKramer i need run many thread in background, and later need modify the content in the thread, i need dynamic add or remove thread, and can find any one by id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For what you requested I would choose that design:**

Implement the Publish Subscribe design pattern ([source code](https://www.cs.sjsu.edu/%7Epearce/modules/patterns/events/pubsubimp.htm)). The `Singleton` class inherits from the `Subscriber` class. The `B` class inherits from the `Publisher` class.

The `B` class has `inline static std::atomic_uint64_t unique_{ 0 }` and `uint64_t id_{ 0 }` private data members. The constructor of `B` increments `++unique_` and assigns `id_ = unique_`. I.e. each `B` object has a unique id. Therefore each `B` object in the `map_` (`std::unordered_map`) has a unique id. IT IS IMPORTANT TO PREVENT COPYING OF B OBJECT!

- On Add: Create a `B` object: `b`, get its id, add its pointer to the `map_`, `subscribe(b)`, and finally: Call `b` to run its thread.

The `B` class has a member function `void Done()`. The thread that **detached** by the `B` object gets the address of `B` object's `Done()` member function as `callback` parameter. When the thread is about to return, it calls the `callback`. IT IS IMPORTANT NOT TO REMOVE/DESTROY AN OBJECT FROM THE MAP AS LONG AS ITS THREAD IS RUNNING!

The implementation of `B::Done()` calls: `notify(id_)` function (of the `Publisher` class).

Since the `Singleton` class is a `Subscriber` its instance intercepts this call on: `void update(Publisher* who, void* what = 0)` **in the context of a `B` object's thread**.

The `Singleton::update` function (override of the `Subscriber`) casts the `void* what` to `uint64_t` (gets the id) and removes the `B` object from its `map_`.

- On Remove: Find in the `map_` the `B` object: `b`, by its id, `unsubscribe(b)`, remove it from the `map_`.

The operation of Add `B` object and Remove `B` object are in the contexts of 2 different threads therefore these places should be guarded with `std::lock_gaurd lk(mutex_)`. I.e. the `Singleton` class should have a `mutable std::mutex mutex_` (`mutable` - M&M rule).